# Using a chef.recipe_url with a password-protected website

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using vagrant to script deployments, and my provisioning clause in my `Vagrantfile` looks like this:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.recipe_url = "http://our.server.com:8081/artifactory/cookbooks/cookbooks.tar.gz"
    chef.add_recipe "vagrant::vagrant_default"
end
```

The problem is that our Artifactory repository is behind HTTP authentication; running chef-solo gives us a `401 Unauthorized (OpenURI::HTTPError)` error.  I tried changing the url to `http://user:pass@our.server.com:8081/artifactory/cookbooks/cookbooks.tar.gz`, but it doesn't work.

How can I access a cookbook URL behind HTTP authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass the credentials in the URL? Something like this:

```
chef.recipe_url = "https[s]://#{the_user}:#{the_password}@our.server.com:8081/artifactory/cookbooks/cookbooks.tar.gz"
```

I'm using similar to download using `remote_file`.

Comment: Tried that, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oops sorry about that. Does url including user and password work in web browser? And did you try https?

Comment: It works in the web browser.  This isn't over https, although we'll get there.  Eventually.

Comment: It might not be supported. Worth asking on the Vagrant mailing list, and maybe filing an issue.

Comment: I believe https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3786 makes sure that HTTPS auth will work.